# Blazor with longer paths failing to load resources

Tags: html, .net, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor app with Swagger UI API documentation.

I noticed, if I used the wrong path so */api/path_with_typo* then it would not load my NotFound page properly, and look all funky (linked resource files, css and js 404 Not Found errors).

I thought it was something to do with the Swagger UI or specific to the api route, but after looking more closely, any non-simple route is doing this, such as:

*/counter/test*

It seems to be due to the browser looking for resources at */counter/css/*.css* instead of */css/*.css*, etc. Hence it's return 404 for those resources and not formatting the page properly.

[image]

I tried mucking around with changing the base path, but that seems to be more for the reverse situation, where the site is under a separate Folder.

I can't seem to find anyone else suffering the same fate? Does that limit Blazor apps to flat structures, a least with the page paths? It's also not great that a typo in the api path will return some ugly, unformatted page...

Comment: How exactly are you looking at those pages?  Because a wrong api path usually results in  a Json error.

Comment: just using the browser. like I said, the problem is that the path is prepended to the resource, so if I type my api path incorrectly, it actually tries to redirect to my Not Found page but all css/js files are then Not Found as well and returning 404 errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, how annoying, it was due to my index.html header order :(

I had previously mucked around with the base tag when deploying to a subsite for testing.

Well, I must have moved it BELOW the css link tags...after comparing to the Jason Taylor RapidBlazor solution, I finally saw that was my mistake, it needs to be ABOVE the links, so that the base tag resets the base url for the links and scripts SMH

```
<base href="/" />
```